# Move control to cursor location?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The think is I would like to show FlowLayoutPanel at mouse cursor location. But with my code bellow it only jumps around center of my form. I'm triggering it on DataGridView.CellMouseEnter event. Asking for some advice, thank you.

```
Private Sub dgw_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgw.CellMouseEnter

   FlowLayoutPane1.Location = Cursor.Position
   FlowLayoutPane1.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Cursor.Position is in screen coordinates.  You need FlowLayoutPane1.Parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position) instead.  The odds that you *really* want this are zero, it is still an entirely random position when the user operates the grid with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MouseMove` instead of the `MouseEnter` event. `MouseEnter` is called only *once* when the mouse ENTERS the control.
Be aware that the `MouseMove` event fires even if the mouse location may be outside of the control.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but it triggers on every cell I'm entering or? But still this changes nothing, there is still problem with spawning location of my FlowLayoutPane. Its still appears at center of form, not even close to my mouse cursor...?

Comment: @Dave: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. If you are talking about positioning, you need to know that the mouse location is always in screen coordinates. Therefore you may use the [PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) function to calculate form coordinates.